# Personalizando uma model de usuarios Laravel 5.4 - Problema no login

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-auth

Eu tentei de tudo já, mas não consigo resolver um problema no sistema de login do `Laravel` que é o seguinte: eu criei uma model chamada `Usuarios`, coloquei todas as informações nela que tem que ser devidamente colocada, como o array `$fillable` e `$hidden`, no entanto, internamente o `Laravel` ainda trata como `model` padrão de login a model User, consegui mudar isso, através dessa linha:

```
protected $table = 'Usuarios';
```

Surgiu outro problema, de não achar o campo `password` que estava padrão (`default`), fui ao arquivo `EloquentUserProvider` e alterei de `password` para `Senha` (*que é como está no eu banco. No entanto agora ele não passa no* `Auth::attempt()`. Fiquei o dia inteiro procurando alguma solução, todas que tentei foi em vão).

Código da model `User`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $model = 'Usuario';
    protected $increments = false;
    protected $table = 'Usuarios';
    protected $primaryKey = 'UsuarioID';

    public function getAuthIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->Senha;
    }

    public function getReminderEmail() {
        return $this->Login;
    }
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Código da model `Usuario`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Usuario extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /*protected $model = 'Usuario';
    protected $increments = false;
    protected $table = 'Usuarios';
    protected $primaryKey = 'UsuarioID';

    public function getAuthIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->Senha;
    }

    public function getReminderEmail() {
        return $this->Login;
    }*/

    protected $fillable = [
        'UsuarioID', 'Nome', 'Login', 'Senha'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'Senha', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Código da função que faz o login no controller:

```
public function entrar(Request $request)
{
    $dadosFormulario=$request->all();
    $dadosLogin=['Login'=>$dadosFormulario['login'],'Senha'=>$dadosFormulario['senha']];

    if( dd(Auth::attempt($dadosLogin)) ){
        return redirect()->route('admin.cursos');
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('site.home');
    }
}
```

*Aqui eu já conferi se os dados estão vindo corretamente do formulário e qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.*

Comment: Pergunto: Pra que alterar?, pra isso funcionar não precisa mudar a class base e autenticação pode ser feita diferente...

Comment: Virgílio, Onde exatamente coloco o código do passo 5?

Comment: @EriksonFlávio coloca na controller de ação que irá ficar responsável por logar o usuário.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sub>**Observação:** Não precisa alterar nada do que vem no `framework` [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) da pasta `vendor` que é o `core`, se houve alterações volte ao que era.</sub>

## Passo a passo:

<sup>***Banco*** [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)</sup>

**1)** Criação do `Model` **`Usuarios`**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Usuarios extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = ['Nome', 'Login', 'Senha'];
    protected $hidden = ['Senha', 'remember_token'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'UsuarioID';
    protected $table = "usuarios";
    
}
```

**2)** `Migration` `Model` `Usuarios`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Usuarios extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('UsuarioID');
            $table->string('Nome');
            $table->string('Login')->unique();
            $table->string('Senha');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('usuarios');
    }
}
```

**3)** Alterar a configuração do arquivo `config\auth.php` na chave `providers`, informando o nova classe que será responsável pela autenticação:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Usuarios::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

**4)** Criação manual dos registros da tabela `Usuarios`:

```
$usuario = Usuarios::create(array(
    'Nome' => 'StackOverFlow',
    'Login' => 'stack@stack.com',
    'Senha' => bcrypt('stack')
));
```

**5)** Para logar com as informações contidas na tabela `Usuarios`:

```
$usuario = Usuarios::where('Login', 'stack@stack.com')
                   ->first();

if (Hash::check('stack', $usuario->Senha))
{
    Auth::loginUsingId($usuario->UsuarioID);
}
```

<sub>**Isso são os cincos passos para `autenticar` em uma aplicação [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) mediante a um código particular e o processo natural tem que ser alterado para esses 5 passos inclusive na hora de logar no sistema.**</sub>

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication)
- [Other Authentication Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#other-authentication-methods)

Comment: Fiz tudo isso, os erros se foram, porém ele não passa no Auth::attempt(), ele sempre retorna false.
Aqui o código do método

`public function entrar(Request $request)
    {
        $dados = $request->all();
        $usuario = Usuario::where('Login', $dados['login'])->first();
        dd($usuario);
            if(Auth::login($usuario)){
                return redirect()->route('admin/cursos');
            } else {
                return 'não entrou no attempt';
            }

    }`

Comment: PS:Já tentei com o Auth::attempt() também, e também me retorna nulo . Abaixo o código do config/auth
`'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Usuario::class,
        ],
    ],`

Comment: @MatheusPicioli não é `Auth::attempt()` é `Auth::loginUsingId($usuario->UsuarioID);` se viu na resposta... Só um coisa, além do conhecimento que já tenho do framework, essa resposta que não é muito habitual é um fato real, testado e funcional, me diz qual erro acontece?

Comment: @@Edit@@
Desculpe o meu desatentamento, esqueci de mudar o campo de comparação, no entando agora ele me retorna esse erro `Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int (SQL: select top 1 * from [Usuarios] where [Usuarios].[UsuarioID] = 86866388`
Algo como se o ID que ele trouxe não esta sendo um GUID

Comment: Aonde está dando esse problema? @MatheusPicioli ?

Comment: Quando chamo o método entrar, ele está retornando esse erro: `QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int (SQL: select top 1 * from [Usuarios] where [Usuarios].[UsuarioID] = 84)`

Código do método entrar está na resposta anterior, não da pra colocar mais linhas aqui

Comment: Consegui o erro era porque tava encarando o GUID como um INTEIRO, e eu pensei que tinha colocado o $incrementing = false na model Usuario, mas eu escrevi errado, estava $increments. Obrigado pela paciencia e colaboração.

Comment: foi sim, já marquei. Obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Eu gostaria de entender o voto negativo, porque, não tem problemas na resposta ou tem?

Comment: Não dei voto negativo, coloquei como melhor resposta.

Comment: E funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: @MatheusPicioli não é você é algum outro usuário que não gostou da resposta, mas, nem deu um motivo para dar um voto negativo. Mas tudo bem!

Comment: Ah, sim, entendi. Se puder dar mais uma ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188405/como-enviar-uma-imagem-din%C3%A2mica-para-o-php-com-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-do-jquery

Comment: @VirgilioNovic porque ele deixou de usar o Auth::attempt($dadosLogin) ??

Comment: @MilrakPereiraPessoa ele mudou a classe que fazia a autenticação e o método `attemp` faz a autenticação mediante dois campos padrões que é `email` e `password`, já a classe dele não tem esses campos então por isso o Laravel abre uma alternativa conforme explicado nessa resposta!

Comment: Dessa forma então não podemos usar o attemp, pois não estaremos utilizando os campos padrões  email e password, agora ficou claro porque devemos usar outra forma de autenticar. Obrigado pela explicação @VirgilioNovic