# Como enviar uma imagem dinâmica para o PHP com a função ajax do jQuery

Tags: jquery, file-upload

Eu tenho uma div em branco, que dinâmicamente ela recebe uma imagem, quase logo que a página carrega, essa imagem é o crop da imagem original, estou conseguindo pegar ela através do código:
`$('.class > img')`
No entando quando jogo isso na função ajax, ele me retorna o número HTTP `500`
Creio que é os nomes que eu esteja passando para o PHP.

Código jQuery:

```
$("#enviar").click(function() {
        console.log($('.image-preview > img')[0] );
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('receber.imagem') }}",
            data:{
                data:new FormData($(".img-preview > img")[0]),
            },
            dataType:'json',
            async:false,
            type:'post',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

Código PHP, PS:Estou usando Laravel 5.4.

```
public function RecebeImagem(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('img-preview'))
    {
        $imagem     = $request->file('img-preview');
        $numero     = rand(1111,9999);
        $diretorio  = "img/uploads";
        $extensao   = $imagem->guessClientExtension();
        $nomeImagem = "imagem_".$numero.".".$extensao;
        $imagem->move($diretorio, $nomeImagem);
        $caminho = $diretorio."/".$nomeImagem;
        //dd($caminho);
        return 'Imagem upada';
    }

    return 'Imagem não upada';
}`
```

Código HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="image-crop">
         <img src="{{ asset('img/profile_small.jpg') }}">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <h4>Preview image</h4>
     <div class="img-preview img-preview-sm"></div>
        <h4>Comon method</h4>
        <p>You can upload new image to crop container and easy download new cropped image.</p>
           <div class="btn-group">
              <label title="Upload image file" for="inputImage" class="btn btn-primary">
              <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file" id="inputImage" class="hide">Upload new image</label>
              <label title="Enviar" id="enviar" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</label>
            </div>
               <h4>Other method</h4>
               <p>You may set cropper options with <code>$(image}).cropper(options)</code></p>
                <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-white" id="zoomIn" type="button">Zoom In</button>
                <button class="btn btn-white" id="zoomOut" type="button">Zoom Out</button>
                <button class="btn btn-white" id="rotateLeft" type="button">Rotate Left</button>
                button class="btn btn-white" id="rotateRight" type="button">Rotate Right</button>
                 <button class="btn btn-warning" id="setDrag" type="button">New crop</button>
               </div>
            </div>
```

Código crop:
`var $image = $(".image-crop > img")
        $($image).cropper({
            aspectRatio: 1.618,
            preview: ".img-preview",
            done: function(data) {
                // Output the result data for cropping image.
            }
        });`

Este código PHP eu utilizei para fazer um upload de imagem.
Não há nenhum erro de import no HTML, tenho 99% de certeza que é o problema são os names, e como eu sei apenas o básico do jQuery está difícil debugar e encontrar aonde está o erro.
PS: Não consigo retornar nada do PHP para o a função Ajax.

Comment: Poste o código inteiro, tem erros que eu já vi, precisaria de um exemplo minimo disso tudo !

Comment: De jQuery e PHP, não tem mais nada, mas tem no HTML

Comment: Precisa colocar o código com um minimo de entendimento assim não tem como!

Comment: Pera ai, vou colocar o código HTML

Comment: Pronto! Vê se da pra entender, colei la, ficou todo quebra, mas acho que da pra entender

Comment: cade o Javascript desse CROP?

Comment: Acho que tu pode experimentar converter essa imagem pra um base64 e aí enviar.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o crop está funcionando perfeitamente, já que a div que recebe a imagem ja cortada, está exibindo normalmente. Mas da uma olhada lá, vou colocar o código.  
Aline com eu posso fazer isso?